# Interactive CUDAFluidDynamics example without CUDA?

Tags: cudalink, fluid-dynamics, cuda

On Macbooks OpenCL works but not CUDA. I saw this fun example [CUDAFluidDynamics](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/CUDALink/ref/CUDAFluidDynamics.html) in the `CUDALink` package and I wanted to play with it, but couldn't.

[image]

Perhaps someone can point me to non-CUDA based implementation or demo, or reference to other particle fluid code (maybe implemented with the new compiler)?

Comment: Just as a side note, you can do fluid dynamics without CUDA by using NDSolve and the FEM as shown for example [here](https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/nonlinear-finite-elements/?product=mathematica). You probably know this but in case you do not there you have a link.

Comment: @user21 yes but I'm interested in a manipulate-able example like this one

Comment: Does it have to function just like that example?

Comment: Absolutely that’s what interested me in this example

Comment: @M.R. It would be nice if you described a problem that you want to solve without reference to `CUDAFluidDynamics[]`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I think part of the interest is that it's a particle-based simulation rather than one coming from solving a PDE with something like FEM or FDM. You can make that fast-ish in Mathematica by judiciously applying `Compile` (I have done this) but it's never gonna be phenomenal.

Comment: @M.R. do you know about `OpenCLLink`?

Comment: @b3m2a1 It is possible that here we need to build a similar solution without using CUDA. At first glance, this is not a problem. But from one drawing I can’t understand what the problem is solved there.

Comment: Just in case, see the code example using CPU on rtfluids.bdevel.org/

Comment: Yes OpenCLLink would be a great route to take if you can reimplement the interactive part of the CUDAFluidDynamics example